# Wiring a counter top fryer

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a deep double fryer I am wiring up, voltage is 208/240, power is 5400/7200 watts, it will be 45 feet from the main electric panel, what size wire and fuses should I use

Comment: What sort of occupancy is this in? Is the wiring going to be exposed or concealed?

Comment: What do the instructions call for?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need 8 AWG copper wire.  Your breaker will need to be 40A and 2-pole.  Unless the labeling or instructions says otherwise.

Comment: Even at 208 Voltage?

Comment: Yes. 5400/208=26amp plus 25 percent equals 32amp therefore 40amp breaker.